# Combine all worksheets in folder VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to append data from all excel worksheets within workbooks stored in the same folder (all workbooks have the same tab/sheet names and I want to append all data from a specific sheet/tab name). Workbooks have different names though.

Comment: Example: All excel sheets have a tab/sheet names "results" and I want to combine/append data from sheet name "results" from all different workbooks in the folder

Comment: Yes, it is possible... Supposing that my understanding is correct: You need to iterate between workbooks from a specific folder, open them one by one and copy each sheet content at the end of existing (with the same sheet name) in a kind of Master workbook. Is that understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I forgot to add though that the workbooks are protected. I have the password though (they all have the same password)

Comment: Do them also have `writeresPassword`?

Comment: Do you like copying all the sheet content, or without the header (if any...)?

Comment: I'd like to copy the header for the first sheet (the sheets all have the same headers  so I only want 1)

Comment: But the sheets where you try merging does not have its own header? Supposing that all sheets (having the same name) have the same number of columns? Is the header in all cases on the first row? Does the range in all cases start from "A1"? And you did anything about the writing protection (password)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try the next code. It iterates between all workbooks in `strFold`, open them (using password) and copy each sheet content in the correspondent one form the master. The header is copied only for the first workbook. It assumes that the headers exists **on the first row** and copied ranges start from A:A column:

```
Sub UpdateAllSheetsWbFolder()
   Dim strFold As String, wbName As String, wb As Workbook, wbM As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, wsM As Worksheet
   Dim lastR As Long, lastRM As Long, lastCol As Long, i As Long
   Const pass As String = "12345" 'use here your real password!
   
   Set wbM = ActiveWorkbook ' if the master one keeps this code: set wbm = ThisWorkbook
   strFold = "C:\...your folder path\" 'take care to end in backslash "\" !!!
   
   wbName = Dir(strFold & "*.xls*")
   
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   Do While wbName <> ""
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(strFold & wbName, Password:=pass)
        i = i + 1
        For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
            Set wsM = wbM.Worksheets(ws.name)
            lastR = ws.Range("A" & ws.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
            lastRM = wsM.Range("A" & wsM.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
            lastCol = ws.cells(1, ws.Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            With ws.Range(ws.cells(IIf(i = 1, 1, 2), "A"), ws.cells(lastR, lastCol))
                wsM.Range("A" & lastRM + IIf(lastRM = 1, 0, 1)).Resize(.rows.count, .Columns.count).Value = .Value
            End With
        Next ws
        
        wb.Close False 'close it without saving
        wbName = Dir()
   Loop
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: @KatyLearnR Glad I could help! But we here, when somebody answer our question in a convenient way, tick the code left side check box in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue will know that suggested solution works...